# Define interaction possibilities between agents in ABM in R

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I have 100 agents in my agent based model and I want them each to have a "social network" of various sizes between 1 and 10. The networks define who they can interact with during the simulation phase. To do this I thought I should build a symmetric matrix which defines who is part of whose social network. This can essentially be picked randomly with the one constraint that if agent 1 is part of agent 2's network then agent 2 is also part of agent 1's network - i.e. the matrix should end up being symmetric.

Has anybody a clue how to set this up? It seems like a simple problem but I am somewhat stumped.

I guess there may also be a clever package to use to build these types of relationships. Recommendations welcome :)

To create a random binary symmetric matrix I have done this:

```
m<-matrix(rbinom(10000,1,0.5),100)
diag(m) <- 0
m[upper.tri(m)] <- t(m)[upper.tri(m)]
```

but I don't know how to ensure the size of each agent's network (or the number of connections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a ragged array of agents they can interact with you could try this:

```
set.seed(123)

# Randomly select the network size for each agent
network.size = sample(1:10,size = 100,replace=TRUE)

# Initialize agents
agents = vector("list",100)

for(i in 1:100) {
  
  if(network.size[i]>0) {
    # Find list of candidate agents for network i
    candidates = which(network.size>0)
    
    # Exclude agent i
    candidates = candidates[candidates!=i]
    
    # In case there aren't enough available agents left to meet the size requirements
    if(length(candidates)<network.size[i]) {
      candidates = which(network.size>0 | sapply(agents,length)<10)
      candidates = candidates[candidates!=i]
    }
    
    if(length(candidates)==1 & network.size[i]==1) {
      # If the number of candidates and the number to sample is 1, just add that candidate
      temp.agents = candidates
    } else {
      # Otherwise sample from available agents
      temp.agents = sample(candidates,network.size[i],replace=FALSE)
    }
    # Add agents to the list
    agents[[i]] = c(agents[[i]],temp.agents)
    
    # Zero out agent i
    network.size[i] = 0
    
    # Go back and add agent i to the list of sampled agents
    for(j in seq(along=temp.agents)) {
      agents[[temp.agents[j]]] = c(agents[[temp.agents[j]]],i)
      network.size[temp.agents[j]] = network.size[temp.agents[j]]-1
    }
  }
  
  agents[[i]] = sort(agents[[i]])
}
```

The list order of `agents` represents each agent. So the first vector in the list corresponds to the agents that agent 1 can interact with.  Notice for instance that the first agent listed for agent 2 is agent 6 and the first agent listed for agent 6 is agent 2.

After that you could possibly make a list of all possible pairs and it looks like you want to assign interaction probabilities?  Sounds like a large fun programming task, but this might get you started on ensuring that the number of people in each network is from 1 to 10 and that each agent shows up in the other agent's network.

Comment: This is great! Thank you! 
The only thing is that some agents still end up with networks larger than 10. I thought the inner for loop takes care of this, specifically network.size[j] = network.size[j]-1 ?

Comment: Do you want their network to have a maximum of 10 agents they interact with or only 9 agents (so 10 agents including themselves)?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want them to have a maximum of 10 agents they can interact with.

Comment: I updated the code to fix the bug that allowed more than 10 agents in a network.  By the end, there aren't enough agents left to meet the sampling needs, so we go back and allow agents with a network less than 10 to increase their network size.